# How to detach from a screen session from within a tmux session?

Tags: tmux, gnu-screen

How to detach from a `screen` session from within a `tmux` session?

I've seen posts of how to detach from `screen` within `screen` and from `tmux` within `tmux`, but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

To add on @atype answer. If the prefix key is same ie <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> then you need to press <kbd>A</kbd> double time then <kbd>D</kbd> ie

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: Somehow, I had to do `ctrl`+`A`+`ctrl`+`A`+`D` for this operation.

Answer (score 4):

`screen` and `tmux` use different prefix keys by default:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for `screen`
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for `tmux`

Just detach from `screen` session by sending <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>. If you configured them both to use the same prefix, `tmux` will pass prefix the second time you press it.